# てを form grammar

Tags: grammar, て-form, particle-を

I encountered this sentence with を directly after て:

バックヤードの小包も減っては増えてを繰り返していたが、今日あたりから減る一方になっていた。

Is this a proper usage of を? I normally see を after either a noun or の.  Here's how I think what the sentence could have been:

バックヤードの小包も減っては増えるのを繰り返していたが、今日あたりから減る一方になっていた。